# Prevent Databricks cluster creation in Standard SKU

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-cli

We're in Databricks Standard SKU, in standard SKU, there is no access control and every users are admin, due to which everybody has previlage to create there own cluster. Is there a way we can restrict the cluster creation for databricks users in stadard SKU.

I know in Premium SKU, we could easily create **groups** and in the **Entitlements** option, we can uncheck the **Allow cluster creation** option. Is there a similar functionality is available in Standard SKU? Any pointers would help.

Also, if somebody starts the Databricks cluster is there a way we can get alerts/notifications.

Answer (score 0):

> **Azure Databricks Standard**

**Databricks** have 5 levels for access control and in the **standard plan**, all are **disabled**.

In **standard**, every user is an admin, and any user can add another user even that does not have access or any resource group or subscription.

[image: Ref1]

> **Azure Databricks Premium**

**Premium**, we have role-based access control. Before working on these make sure it’s enabled.

[image: Ref2]

> **Databricks cluster is there a way we can get alerts/notifications ?**

Yes, You can get alerts/notifications. Please follow the below reference it has detail information about Azure Databricks alert and standard, premium Databricks .

**Reference:**

[Azure Databricks-Alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/jobs#advanced-job-options)

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-databricks-standard-vs-premium-ashish-kumar

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/user/alerts/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACN01NYXGRU&t=712s